# Declaration of a private array accessed by pointer in a class and memory allocation

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, runtime-error, bus-error

I need some help with an in-class declaration of a pointer. I'm looking for a way to use a c-style array (so unfortunately no vectors) although I use c++. I can't manage to have no errors in execution such as "segmentation fault: 11" or "bus error: 10". The purpose is to have a way to contain 10 references to people in a class.

These pointers are declared in the .h file in this way:

```
private:
string * name;
string * surname;
int * index1;
int * index2;
```

and in the ctor in the .cc file I've used different ways to allocate memory, such as:

```
string * name = new string[10];
string * surname = new string[10];
int * index1 = new int[10];
int * index2 = new int[10];
```

but I got runtime errors, maybe because it actually doesn't access the private variables or it exceeds memory ("segmentation fault").
If I don't write the lines above, the output is "bus error" while executing.
I don't get errors in compilation, only during the execution. 
I can't change the private variable types in .h file and it doesn't allow me to use new in the class as it would be an extension of C++11.

Any help would be very appreciated

Comment: Those are local variables and are hiding your object instance members. The types (`string *`, etc..) shouldn't be there in the actual c-tor (and arguably you should be using `std::vector<>`s in the first place regardless).

Comment: In your ctor the decalration should be like `name = new string[10]` and so..

Comment: Thank you for your fast replies, but I tried also in that way and it returns a runtime error

Comment: please provide a [mcve], as it stands, very little help can be given

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use std::vector, as there's very little reason for beginners to use new/delete.

In your case the private section could change to:

```
private:
std::vector<string> name;
std::vector<string> surname;
std::vector<int> index1;
std::vector<int> index2;
```

and in the constructor,  could have this:

```
name.resize(10);
surname.resize(10);
index1.resize(10);
index2.resize(10);
```

Comment: Better yet, use a member initializer list and have an empty constructor body

Comment: OP actually explicitly said "no vectors"

Comment: @PasserBy OP seems to be a novice and it seems better to me that they be given a better alternative than new/delete

Comment: Even if that was the case, a `vector` based answer should be a supplement to a direct answer imo